# How to use Multiple select tag in single line while using bootstrap?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

We want to display **birthday** in **dropdown** list

How to use **Multiple select tag** in single line while using bootstrap?

```
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label>Birthday</label><br>  
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option value="jan">Jan</option>
      <option value="jan">Feb</option>
      <option value="jan">Mar</option>
       ................
      <option value="jan">Dec</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
      <option value="">Day</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      ................
      <option value="jan">12</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
      <option value="">Year</option>
      <option value="1992">1992</option>
      <option value="1993">1993</option>
      <option value="1994">1994</option>
      ................
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

[image]

**Note**: we are using **bootstrap**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use the `form-inline` class on the parent element...

```
<div class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
    <label>Birthday</label><br>  
    <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
      <option value="jan">Jan</option>
      <option value="jan">Feb</option>
      <option value="jan">Mar</option>
       ................
      <option value="jan">Dec</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
      <option value="">Day</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      ................
      <option value="jan">12</option>
    </select>
    <select class="form-control" id="sel2">
      <option value="">Year</option>
      <option value="1992">1992</option>
      <option value="1993">1993</option>
      <option value="1994">1994</option>
      ................
      <option value="2015">2015</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/D3PIBmKMt0)